# Can't retrieve custom title of OSX terminal tabs

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript

I'm trying to select a certain terminal tab in OSX and send keystrokes to it. But Terminal in OSX 10.8.4 doesn't seem to store anything but "Terminal" for a tab's custom title, even if you set a custom title with the inspector. Any ideas? Here is the code I'd like to use to select the right tab:

```
tell application "Terminal"
  set allWindows to number of windows

  repeat with i from 1 to allWindows
    set allTabs to number of tabs of window i
    repeat with j from 1 to allTabs
      if custom title of tab j of window i contains "blah" then
        set frontmost of window i to true
        set selected of tab j of window i to true
      end if
    end repeat
  end repeat
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on an older version of OSX, so I couldn't duplicate your problem (your code works fine for me), but perhaps try:

```
if ((custom title of (current settings of (tab j of (window i)))) as string) contains "blah" then
```

Comment: @CarlYoungblood Ahh, well in that case I would suggest looking into the AppleScript Library and seeing if you can find the proper syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set the tab name this way:

```
tell "application" "Terminal"
# ...
  set the_tab to tab 1 of the front window -- replace with your tab selector
  tell settings set "Basic"
      set custom title of the_tab to "My Tab Name"
  end tell
# ...
end tell
```

You should be able to get retrieve the tab name:

```
tell "application" "Terminal"
     set the_name to custom title of the_tab as string
end tell
```

Works for me on OSX 10.8.4